# Show that $R\cong Rx$ (as rings) if and only if $x$ is an unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $x$ is non zero element in $R$. Show that $R\cong Rx$ (as rings) if and only if $x$ is an unit.

I know that $x\in R$ is a unit if there exist $y\in R$ such that $xy=1$.
What the hint to proof this theorem?

I try to prove like this.
Given $R\cong Rx$, so there exist an isomorphism $\theta : R\to Rx$. Now I confuse how to define the $\theta$ mapping. I can't associate with the unit element definition.

Comment: In a first step you can show, that they are equal as sets. If you know this, the identity is a fine isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be the ring isomorphism $R\to Rx$. It's obvious that $\phi(1)$ is a nonzero idempotent of $Rx$, that is, $\phi(1)^2=\phi(1)$.

Suppose $\phi(1)=rx$.  Since the image is also an integral domain, you can cancel the expression $rxrx=rx$ to get $rx=1$. At that point, you would have discovered $x$ is a unit.